# Does ContentResolver.applyBatch run on separate thread

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentresolver

I need to record the time taken for an update in the contacts table. If I run the following code for the above mentioned [`ContentResolver.applyBatch`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#applyBatch%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E%29),

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
act.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
int seconds1 = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
Log.d(TAG, "diff @ "+(seconds1-seconds));
```

The output is `diff @ 0`. But it actually takes around 15-20 seconds for an update of around 150 records.

Does it run on a separate thread?
How can I record the time taken for the update of a record in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use System.currentTimeMillis();

Comment: and whats wrong with the above code?
System.currentTimeMillis() gives me 5555 as a diff value. it does make a 5.5 second value so my code should also work, that's what I'm asking.